# validation errors are popping up also when they don't apply to the error

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

This code is supposed to take the weight that is inputted by the user in KG and the number of packets inputted by the user and convert it to the selected radio conversion as a text. But I am unable to any result. It keeps popping up as an error even when all the inputted values are correct and it shows all of my validation errors at once even though most don't even apply to that scenario.

```
<div id="content">
    
<h3> This page calculates total weight of packets, given weight of one packet in kgs and number of packets and print the result in selected unit(Pounds, Ounce, Kilograms) in a new text box</h3>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" action="/webd2201/mirzaa/test2.php" >

<p>Weight of a packet in Kilograms: <input type="text" name="kilogram" value = "" size="10" /></p>
<p>Total number of packets&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" name="number" value = "" size="10" /></p>

<p>Select the unit for total weight (Pounds, Ounce or Kilograms):</p>
<p>
    Pounds<input type="radio" name="select" value ="Lbs" checked="checked"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Ounce<input type="radio" name="select" value ="Oz"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Kilograms<input type="radio" name="select" value ="Kgs"/>
</p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Caculate and Convert" /></p>

</form>
</div>  
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$error = "";


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
{
    $W_KG = "";
    $P_Num = "";
    $result = "";
}

else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $W_KG=trim($_POST["Weight in KG"]);
    $P_Num=trim($_POST["Number of packets"]);
    $result=trim($_POST["Result"]);


    //if weight in KG is null
    if(!isset($W_KG))
    {
        $error.="Please select a value for weight <br/>";
    }
    //if the number of packets is null
    if(!isset($P_Num))
    {
        $error.="You must enter number of packets <br/>";
    }
    //non-numeric weight in kg value
    if(!is_numeric($W_KG))
    {
        $error .= "The weight MUST be a number, you entered: " . $W_KG . "<br/>";
        $W_KG = "";
    }
    //nin numeric number of packet value
    if(!is_numeric($P_Num))
    {
        $error .= "The number of packets MUST be a number, you entered: " . $P_Num . "<br/>";
        $P_Num = "";
    }
    //Weight must be greater than 0
    if(($W_KG)<=0)
    {
        $error .="The weight must be a positive number, you entered: " . $W_KG . "<br />";
        $W_KG = "";
    }
    //number of packets must be greater than 0
    if(($P_Num)<=0)
    {
        $error .="Number of Packets must be a positive number, you entered: " . $P_Num . "<br />";
        $P_Num = "";
    }
        
    if($error == "")
    {  

        $result = ($W_KG * $P_Num);

        if($radioVal == "Lbs")
        {   
            $result = ($result * $KG_LB); 
            echo "Total converted value in Lbs is: " . $result;
            $result = "";
        }
        if($radioVal == "Oz")
        {
            $result = ($result * $KG_OZ);
            echo "Total converted value in Oz is: " . $result;
            $result = "";
        }
        else if($radioVal == "Kgs")
        {
            echo "Total converted value in Kg is: " . $result ;
            $result = "";
        }
                
    }

    else
    {
        $error .= "<br/>Please try again."; 
        $Color = "red";

    echo '<b><div style="Color:'.$Color.'">'.$error.'</div></b>';
        
    }
}       















include ("./footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($W_KG))` should be `if(!isset($W_KG))`, same with the `$P_Num` one. Also, a lot of these can be combined. Such as ` if(!isset($W_KG) && $W_KG <= 0)`

Comment: Where does `$incr` come from?

Comment: I added the result code and added the incr part by accident from another code

Comment: Also I need to have seperate error messages so I have to make separate validations

Comment: I still cant figure out why all of my errors are popping up at once and why I cant display my final answer if there are no errors

Comment: any help will be fine.